# Select top value within group return all

Tags: r

Using the following data frame

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
                 gender = c('M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'),
                 index = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

And I need to take the max value of `index` with each `id` so I was thinking `top_n` function would work but I actually need the max value to be repeated for each id. So something like this is the result I need:

```
df_result <- data.frame(id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
                 gender = c('M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'),
                 index = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 max_index = c(3, 3, 3, 4 ,4, 4, 4))
```

Is there something other than `top_n` that I can use, or use it but have it repeat?

Comment: `with(df, ave(index, id, FUN = max))`

Comment: `tapply(df$index,df$id,max)` does your job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(max_index = max(index))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
  id    gender index max_index
  <chr> <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A     M          1         3
2 A     M          2         3
3 A     M          3         3
4 B     F          1         4
5 B     F          2         4
6 B     F          3         4
7 B     F          4         4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `base` package only:

```
max_ind <- tapply(df$index,df$id,max)
max_index <- max_ind[df$id]
cbind(df,max_index)

#  id gender index max_index
#1  A      M     1         3
#2  A      M     2         3
#3  A      M     3         3
#4  B      F     1         4
#5  B      F     2         4
#6  B      F     3         4
#7  B      F     4         4
```

I hope this is what you want.